# How do I log to a new file every day in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to create a new log file for rails application everyday.

The goal is to go from standard `production.log` to

`production.2019-06-01.log`

`production.2019-06-02.log`

...etc

Where the latest log is has today's date.

I am aware of `logrotate` application but the issue is that `production.log` is current one, `production.log.1` is supposedly yesterdays. So if you want to find something that happened on a specific day few weeks ago, you'll need to eyeball which log file it will be in.

Comment: `logrotate` has `dateext` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try :

```
logger = Logger.new('production.log', 'daily') # or 'weekly', 'monthly'
```

To get the desired output use :

```
t = Time.now()
file = 'production.' + (t.strftime("%m-%d-%y")) + '.log' 
logger = Logger.new(file, 'daily') # or 'weekly', 'monthly'
```

Comment: Yes. It creates `production.log` instead of `production.2019-06-13.log`

Comment: You'll only see it roll over when you hit a new day.

Comment: Please have a look on my answer again. I edited the default log name `file = 'production.' + (t.strftime("%m-%d-%y")) + '.log'` to get exactly what you need. Good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

you can configure logrotate to do what you need check `daily` and `dateext` options here https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate.
also you can use the more modern way and use something like ELK https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack to index the logs in elasticsearch and use kibana dashboard to search your logs easily.

Answer (score 0):

All great answers! I am currently running on tomcat, so I utilized the default java logging classes to do this.